# Java REST web service how to consume complex XML

Tags: java, rest, xml-parsing, jaxb

We can convert XSD to Java Object using JAXB. If XML has multiple elements it creates multiple classes out of it. JAXB has created multiple classes for following XML:

```
    <cXML payloadID="dfbgw859yjdfngoho9gj" timestamp="12/12/2012 4:51:22 PM" xml:lang=" en-us ">
<Header>
<From>
<Credential domain="web">
<Identity>UAT Master</Identity>
</Credential>
</From>
<To>
<Credential domain="web">
<Identity>notused</Identity>
</Credential>
</To>
<Sender>
<Credential domain="web">
<Identity>notused</Identity>
</Credential>
</Sender>
</Header>
<Request>
<OrderRequest>
<OrderRequestHeader orderDate="12/12/2012 4:51:22 PM" type="new">
<ID domain="Web">645</ID>
<Total>
<Money currency="USD">129.48</Money>
</Total>
<Shipping>
<Money currency="USD">12.57</Money>
<Description xml:lang="en-US"/>
</Shipping>
<Tax>
<Money currency="USD">8.91</Money>
</Tax>
<Extrinsic name="Additional Comments or Instructions:"/>
<BillTo>
<Address contactId="210306">
<CompanyName>UAT Master</CompanyName>
<ContactId domain="Web">210306</ContactId>
<PaymentType>CREDITCARD</PaymentType>
<PostalAddress name="default">
<FirstName>test</FirstName>
<LastName>test</LastName>
<Street>9050 Malabar Hills</Street>
<City>Newark</City>
<State>NJ</State>
<Country isoCountryCode="USA">USA</Country>
<PostalCode>40485</PostalCode>
<Email>test@test.com</Email>
<WorkPhone>2342423434</WorkPhone>
</PostalAddress>
</Address>
</BillTo>
<Extrinsic name="Purchase Order Number:"/>
<Contact Role="buyer">
<ID domain="Web">testName</ID>
<Name>testName M</Name>
<Email>testName.testLastName@test.com</Email>
<Company>UAT Master</Company>
<Department/>
</Contact>
</OrderRequestHeader>
<ItemOut quantity="120" lineNumber="1">
<Type>PRINT</Type>
<ItemId domain="Web">210300</ItemId>
<StatusType>APPROVED</StatusType>
<PostageAmount currency="USD">0.00</PostageAmount>
<Discount currency="USD">0.00</Discount>
<orderItemName>cxml test for cc payment</orderItemName>
<orderItemDescription>test cxml only with cc payment</orderItemDescription>
<Price>108.00</Price>
<ItemID>
<SupplierPartID>BUSCRD001</SupplierPartID>
<SupplierPartAuxiliaryID/>
</ItemID>
<ItemDetail>
<URL>
http://127.0.1.1/Agggf/NgA=/Mfsdfsf==/2012/3/28/dfafDYAMgA1AA==.jpg
</URL>
<Description xml:lang="en-US">Business Card</Description>
<UnitPrice>
<Money currency="USD">0.90</Money>
</UnitPrice>
<UnitOfMeasure>PER_PIECE</UnitOfMeasure>
<Extrinsic name="options">
<ul>
<li>
Color/Yellow=
<span>0.00</span>
</li>
<li>
Paper Type/Gloss=
<span>0.00</span>
</li>
</ul>
</Extrinsic>
<Classification domain=""/>
<ManufacturerPartID/>
<ManufacturerName xml:lang="en-US"/>
</ItemDetail>
<ShipTo>
<Address contactId="210301">
<ContactId domain="Web">210301</ContactId>
<CompanyName>UAT Master</CompanyName>
<PostalAddress name="default">
<FirstName>test</FirstName>
<LastName>test</LastName>
<Street>9050 Great Hills</Street>
<City>Newark</City>
<State>New Jersey</State>
<Country isoCountryCode="USA">USA</Country>
<PostalCode>78759</PostalCode>
<Email>testName.testLastName@test.com</Email>
<WorkPhone>2342423434</WorkPhone>
</PostalAddress>
</Address>
</ShipTo>
<Shipping>
<Money currency="USD">12.57</Money>
<Description xml:lang="en-US">USPS Ground</Description>
</Shipping>
<Distribution>
<Accounting name="DistributionCharge">
<AccountingSegment id="">
<Name xml:lang="en-US"/>
<Description xml:lang="en-US"/>
</AccountingSegment>
<AccountingSegment id="">
<Name xml:lang="en-US"/>
<Description xml:lang="en-US"/>
</AccountingSegment>
</Accounting>
<Charge>
<Money currency="USD"/>
</Charge>
</Distribution>
<Distribution>
<Accounting name="DistributionCharge">
<AccountingSegment id="">
<Name xml:lang="en-US"/>
<Description xml:lang="en-US"/>
</AccountingSegment>
<AccountingSegment id="">
<Name xml:lang="en-US"/>
<Description xml:lang="en-US"/>
</AccountingSegment>
</Accounting>
<Charge>
<Money currency="USD"/>
</Charge>
</Distribution>
<Comments xml:lang="en-US"/>
</ItemOut>
</OrderRequest>
</Request>
</cXML>
```

I have to write a REST service which can accept this xml with multiple elements. I was succesful in accepting a simple xml because it had only single class.
How to achieve this.

```
@POST
    @Path("/XMLTest")
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    public Response consumeXML(**WhichObjectToAcceptHere whichObject**) {

        String output = objectFactory.toString();

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
```

Comment: Probably the class that was created for your `cXML` tag. Do you have a class like that?

Comment: These are the classed created by JAXB for above XML: AccountingSegmentType
AccountingType
AddressType
BillToType
CXMLType
ChargeType
ClassificationType
CommentsType
ContactIdType
ContactType
CountryType
CredentialType
DescriptionType
DiscountType
DistributionType
ExtrinsicType
FromType
HeaderType
IDType
ItemDetailType
ItemIDType
ItemOutType
LiType
ManufacturerNameType
MoneyType
NameType
ObjectFactory
OrderRequestHeaderType
OrderRequestType
PostageAmountType
PostalAddressType
RequestType
SenderType
ShipToType
ShippingType
TaxType
ToType
TotalType
UlType
UnitPriceType

Comment: Try `CXMLType` then.